# Samsung galaxy tab 2 7" gt p3110

Tags: samsung-mobile

I just bought this tablet with Android 4.0.3 and at the store they told me that this model has 8GB, when I check on settings, I only have 4GB. Why? Does the operating system consume 4gb? I'm new at this i'm sorry.

Comment: This is off topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is way off topic for Stack Overflow.

But to answer your question, The 8GB quoted is the raw hard drive size. i.e. Before drive formatting and OS install.

When drive formatting and OS install has taken place the storage available to the user is usually considerably less.

Saying that, a loss of 50% seems like a lot.